# Advanced VType for password verification on extjs4 enhancement needed

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs

I want to implement a password verification using advanced VType on extjs taken from http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html, but look like the confirm password text field does not validate on the change of password text field if the password confirm doesn't have values (if password value is 'test' and confirm password value is blank then the form is valid). I'm sure this is not a right thing.
How to make/force the confirm password text field to be valid/invalid by following condition:

1. If password value not equal to confirm password value then confirm
   password is invalid (even if confirm password value is blank)
2. If password value is blank and confirm password value is blank to
   then confirm password is valid
3. If password value is equal to confirm password value then confirm
   password is valid

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok look like I've solved my own problem.
As Molecule Man said it's cannot be achieved (easily).

I need to override Ext.form.field.Text.getErrors to solve that

```
Ext.form.field.Text.override({
    getErrors: function(value) {
        var me = this,
            errors = me.callParent(arguments),
            validator = me.validator,
            emptyText = me.emptyText,
            allowBlank = me.allowBlank,
            vtype = me.vtype,
            vtypes = Ext.form.field.VTypes,
            regex = me.regex,
            format = Ext.String.format,
            msg;

        value = value || me.processRawValue(me.getRawValue());

        if (Ext.isFunction(validator)) {
            msg = validator.call(me, value);
            if (msg !== true) {
                errors.push(msg);
            }
        }

        if (value.length < 1 || value === emptyText) {
            if (!allowBlank) {
                errors.push(me.blankText);
            }
            //FIX BY ME : NEED TO COMMENT THIS BECAUSE ITS CAN IGNORING VTYPE AS ITS IMMEDIATELY RETURN ERRORS
            //return errors;
        }

        if (value.length < me.minLength) {
            errors.push(format(me.minLengthText, me.minLength));
        }

        if (value.length > me.maxLength) {
            errors.push(format(me.maxLengthText, me.maxLength));
        }

        if (vtype) {
            if(!vtypes[vtype](value, me)){
                errors.push(me.vtypeText || vtypes[vtype +'Text']);
            }
        }

        if (regex && !regex.test(value)) {
            errors.push(me.regexText || me.invalidText);
        }

        return errors;
    }
});
```

Here is the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/gajahlemu/SY6WC/

Answer (score 1):

Looking for help on your post I have found an easy solution. Starting from the mentioned [extjs4 example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html) it is sufficient to add following 'onchange' listener to 'pass' field (...it is copy from your solution + one more line):

```
listeners: {  
    change: function(field) {  
        var confirmField = field.up('form').down('[name=pass-cfrm]');  
        confirmField.allowBlank = (field.value == '');  // <- the change is here
        confirmField.validate();  
    }  
},
```

The 'allowBlank' property of 'pass-cfrm' field is changed dynamically according to value of 'pass' field. If 'pass' field is empty then 'pass-cfrm' is optional (allowBlank = true), otherwise it is required (allowBlank = false)

Answer (score 0):

The second point cannot be achieved (easily). Because it would require setting allowBlank to true for both inputs. And allowBlank has higher priority then vtypes. So in cases when one field is blank and the second one is not blank the blank field would be valid (whereas it must be invalid) because of `allowBlank: true`.

If we abandon the second point the solution can be very easy:

- add `allowBlank: false` to both fields;
- revalidate confirm field on password field `change`

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/PZ8ay/).

Comment: How to achieve all condition, without ignoring one of those three? Because I want to make a user form that can edit user name and/or password. but if the password leave blank its assume that user don't change the password.